# how to rebuild / reinstall ssrs (reportserver, reportservertempdb) databases?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

Our server crashed. We got it back up and running however, the mentioned databases have been corrupted.

Is there a programmatic / automatic way of rebuilding or reinstalling the SSRS databases?

If not:

1. Since we can still **select *** from the databases, how do I grab the permissions and roles on different reports?
2. How do we retrieve subscription information?

Comment: Do you have backups you can recover from?

Answer (score -1):

I’m not 100% sure but I think there is no supported way to rebuild these.

If you have backups of these databases then just restore them. If not you can try creating another empty database and then try to synchronize structure and data and see if that can help.

I’d suggest you use some third party tools for this.